# LWC show records

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a list of records. I need to display each one with some record data. Each row has to have a radio button and a number input field.

```
<radio>  <number> ---  Product1 Name    --- Product1 Description   --   product1 price
<radio>  <number> ---  Product2 Name    --- Product2 Description   --   product2 price
```

...

after a submit, I need to get the number from the selected product and move on

I'm looking for some guidance on the best approach to do this in LWC. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification):

```
<lightning-datatable 
  columns={columnHeaders} 
  data={products} 
  key-field="Id"
  max-row-selection="1">
```

On submit, you can call getSelectedRows():

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  let selections = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').getSelectedRows();
```

The selected item, if any, will be in index 0.

You can read the documentation for the specific format options available in `columnHeaders`.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of using lightning-datatable . . .  what about the number selection? I wasn't very clear on that. <number> is more like a quantity. I need to know how many

Comment: @mackmama The selected row will be the item's Id, and you just need to get the original row from the data.

Comment: @sfdxfox - sorry, I'm not clear on how to get the quantity

<radio>     quantity(not on the record)    <name>      <description>    <unit price>

Comment: @mackmama Where are you trying to get the quantity from? I'm not certain what you're asking.

Comment: In a particular row, I want to be able to enter a quantity for the product that is being displayed in that row.  So if I'm displaying widget2, I want to be able to put a quantity in that row. For example, I want to order n widget2 products